# VC++ PPL, assigning a Scheduler to a task_group

Tags: task, scheduler, ppl

Pretend we have a class:

```
class Foo
{
private:
 Concurrency::task_group _tasks;  
};
```

How do I assign a scheduler to this task_group? I do not want to use the default scheduler as I also use parallel_for elsewhere in the code.

The task_group will have it's level of maxconcurrency set through the scheduler to use either all cores, or a subset of them depending on the hour. The application may run for hours, so the maxconcurrency will be required to change.

I cannot find a nice way of doing this in PPL. In .NET this is very easy - all you have to do is set MaxDegreeOfParallelism.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There are several solutions:

1. If you use the MSVS C++ 2012 than:

   ```
   _tasks.run([]()
   {
       Context::Oversubscribe(true);
       //
       // long time running task
       //
      Context::Oversubscribe(false);
   });
   ```
2. If you APP works on Win7x64 or Windows Server 2008 R2 than try [UMS](http://blogs.msdn.com/themes/blogs/generic/post.aspx?WeblogApp=nativeconcurrency&y=2010&m=07&d=26&WeblogPostName=the-promise-of-ums&GroupKeys=):

   ```
   Scheduler::SetDefaultSchedulerPolicy( SchedulerPolicy(1, SchedulerKind, UmsThreadDefault) );
   ```
3. And last. Create new curren sheduler with new oversubscribe policy (enlarge MaxConcurrency) befor create new heavy time task.

   ```
   CurrentScheduler::Create( SchedulerPolicy(1, MaxConcurrency, 8) );
   _tasks.run([](){
       //
       // long time running task
       //
    });
   CurrentScheduler::Detach();
   ```

Comment: I tried #3 and it only worked on the first pass. In my larger method that is run N times, I use a parallel_for (set with defaults and the scheuler to use all cores ==> SchedulerPolicy(1, MaxConcurrency, LogicalCoreCount)). Then after that I use essentially what you have in #3, but I set the MaxConcurrency to (LogicalCoreCount - 1). I can see the work usage railing to 87%... but on the next pass it goes to 100% and ignores my MaxConcurrency SchedulerPolicy.<br>

Comment: Perhaps in the second case, the current scheduler was occupied some other concurrence task, and was not able to release the logical processor, making 100% CPU usage.

Try to use Scheduler class to manage a scheduler instance - [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513829.aspx):

Comment: Example:

    const UINT nProcessorCount = std::max<>(1, Concurrency::GetProcessorCount() - 1);
    cheduler* scheduler = Scheduler::Create(SchedulerPolicy(1, MaxConcurrency, nProcessorCount));
    scheduler->Attach();
     
    // run your task
    
    CurrentScheduler::Detach();
    scheduler->Release();

Comment: a little clarification: MaxConcurrency should be scale factor from Concurrency::GetProcessorCount(). only in this case it is possible to predict the CPU usage.

Comment: User-mode schedulable (UMS) threads are not supported in the Concurrency Runtime in Visual Studio 2012. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492665(v=vs.110).aspx I have no idea why they removed that.